# How to identify and correct corruption of Ubuntu installation?

Tags: nvidia, reinstall, data-corruption, reinstalling, memtest

I set up a new computer with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64)

It was working fine for a while but then started giving me address boundary errors and my Unity desktop theme screwed up, missing icons, etc.:

[image: Unity icons blank]

The only explanation I have is that I had enabled Nvidia and Intel proprietary drivers:

[image: proprietary drivers list]

and it seems to have not happened since I turned them off.  But the desktop is still screwed up and I don't trust anything else that may have been corrupted.

I ran destructive badblocks on all the HDDs before installing them and fsck seems fine on all of them.  I ran memtest for a while and it didn't find any errors:

[image: memtest]

I can run `sudo debsums -sa` and it only finds files that I have intentionally changed.  How do I confirm the cause and how do I repair any corrupted files?

Comment: GT630 can and *should* use any of the Nvidia versions proposed in your screenshot without a problem. I had one a few years ago and it always worked fine with the latest Nvidia driver. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Actually I re-enabled the Intel microcode for a week and didn't see any problems, then re-enabled the Nvidia driver today and when I try to run GL tests I get "SIGSEGV Address Boundary Error" again, so it's apparently the Nvidia driver.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Then I tried to install an older Nvidia driver and it failed and hosed my apt, with `libcuda1-340` `in a very bad inconsistent state`.  Eventually I got it uninstalled and gave up on nvidia drivers.  Then I noticed the Theme was not set, so I set it to Ambiance and the icons and window borders are back to normal